# Trouble getting past tkinter portion of code and back to main program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written my first Tkinter script to get text from the user. All is working, except my program stops after the code below and doesn't continue with my first line of the main program.
*Any help for a newbie would be greatly appreciated.*

```
import tkinter as tk

master_window = tk.Tk()
master_window.geometry("300x300")  # Set the size of the window
master_window.title("File Type")   # Set the title of the window

def print_data():
    file_type = string_variable.get()  # Get the value from the entry widget
    print(f"You entered: {file_type}")  # Print the file type

string_variable = tk.StringVar(master_window)

label = tk.Label(master_window, text="Enter A, B, C or D: ")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry = tk.Entry(master_window, textvariable=string_variable)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

button = tk.Button(master_window, text="Enter", command=print_data)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

master_window.mainloop()

date_range = "3-4 to 3-8-2024"
output_filename = "RC2X Summary 3-14-2024.txt"
post_filename = "RC2X_3-14-2024-POST.txt"
post_filedate = "3142024"

# Variable assignment section
i=0
j=0
p=0
sent_count = 0
return_count = 0
```

I've tried printing at various stages, but it prints and then locks up without continue the code after the last line above. I have to <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to out.

Comment: That's how Tkinter _works_. GUI programs are different to the scripts you may have written before - they wait for events (like button clicks, keystrokes, etc.) and allow your program to handle them. That's what the main loop is doing.

Comment: It might help if you showed the code after the call to `master_window.mainloop()` so people can see what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: Okay. So, I have Tkinter code above this that asks for two files and saves the filenames. Once I enter those, it proceeds to the code in my question. Once I have entered the text A, B, C. or D above in the button, then what is the event that it is waiting for?

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the code, rather than putting it in comments, so it's easy to read

Comment: Okay, will do. New at this . . .

Comment: GUI programs wait _indefinitely_ for events, until they're terminated.

Comment: So, sounds like I need to terminate after the master_window.mainloop() line? Or just prior to it?

Comment: You're misunderstanding. The main loop is in control. If you want to initialise variables, you can do that before you start the loop. From then on, to modify them, you do that based on whatever events you care about. For example, when you press a button, it could grab the new value from a text field and assign it to whatever variable is relevant.

Comment: If you really do want to terminate the loop, there will be a way to do it. You'll have to check the Tkinter docs for how to do that and obviously do it when the relevant event happens (e.g. clicking on a "Quit" button).

Comment: Thanks. I'll peruse the Tkinter documentation. Thx for the assistance.